# CMSG_NXTHDR() returns NULL even though there are more cmsghdr objects

Tags: linux, sockets

I need to send some ancillary data over a Unix domain socket, but I'm having problems creating a `msghdr`. I can only seem to access the first `cmsghdr` in `msghdr.msg_control`. `CMSG_NXTHDR()` returns NULL no matter how large I make `msghdr.msg_control`.

I'm running 64-bit Linux 3.13.0 with `eglibc` 2.19, if that matters. Here is some sample code that demonstrates the problem. I compiled it with `gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Werror -Wpedantic test.c`. I'm aware that I could send both file descriptors in the same message—this is just a test.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main()
{
    int data1 = STDIN_FILENO;
    int data2 = STDOUT_FILENO;

    char control[CMSG_SPACE(sizeof(data1)) + CMSG_SPACE(sizeof(data2))];
    struct msghdr mh = {
        .msg_namelen = 0,
        .msg_iovlen = 0,
        .msg_control = control,
        .msg_controllen = sizeof(control),
        .msg_flags = 0
    };

    struct cmsghdr *cmh = CMSG_FIRSTHDR(&mh);
    if (cmh == NULL) {
        puts("Can't get first cmsg");
        return 1;
    }
    cmh->cmsg_len = CMSG_LEN(sizeof(data1));
    cmh->cmsg_level = SOL_SOCKET;
    cmh->cmsg_type = SCM_RIGHTS;
    memcpy(CMSG_DATA(cmh), &data1, sizeof(data1));

    cmh = CMSG_NXTHDR(&mh, cmh);
    if (cmh == NULL) {
        puts("Can't get second cmsg");
        return 1;
    }
    cmh->cmsg_len = CMSG_LEN(sizeof(data2));
    cmh->cmsg_level = SOL_SOCKET;
    cmh->cmsg_type = SCM_RIGHTS;
    memcpy(CMSG_DATA(cmh), &data2, sizeof(data2));
}
```

When I build and run this program, it prints "Can't get second cmsg". This is true even if I increase the size of `control` by hundreds of bytes. Apparently `CMSG_NXTHDR()` doesn't think there is a second `cmsghdr` in `.msg_control`. How can I convince it that there are two of them, not just one?

Answer (score 5):

I had couple of hours wasted on this issue, so thought document what I found. 
It is a case of uninitialised control buffer. The man pages does not instruct about this specifically but if you look in the header file /usr/include/bits/socket.h, the code reads as

```
_EXTERN_INLINE struct cmsghdr *
__NTH (__cmsg_nxthdr (struct msghdr *__mhdr, struct cmsghdr *__cmsg))
{
    if ((size_t) __cmsg->cmsg_len < sizeof (struct cmsghdr))
    /* The kernel header does this so there may be a reason.  */
    return (struct cmsghdr *) 0;

    __cmsg = (struct cmsghdr *) ((unsigned char *) __cmsg
                   + CMSG_ALIGN (__cmsg->cmsg_len));

    if ((unsigned char *) (__cmsg + 1) > ((unsigned char *) __mhdr->msg_control
                                          + __mhdr->msg_controllen)
        || ((unsigned char *) __cmsg + CMSG_ALIGN (__cmsg->cmsg_len)
         > ((unsigned char *) __mhdr->msg_control + __mhdr->msg_controllen)))
         /* No more entries.  */
             return (struct cmsghdr *) 0;

     return __cmsg;
 }
```

After the first check, the __cmsg is made to point to an address which is treated as the next header. Subsequently, the rhs expression on second if statements, uses the value of __cmsg->cmsg_len which could be a garbage if you have not initialised the control buffer first. Depending on the garbage value, you could have the possibility of this check failing and thus resulting in a null value no matter how much you pump up the size of control buffer.

Solution could be as simple as(from your code)

`char control[CMSG_SPACE(sizeof(data1)) + CMSG_SPACE(sizeof(data2))] = {};`

That did it for me.

Comment: According to `man 3 cmsg` https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/cmsg.3.html#DESCRIPTION , `cmsgs.data` should be zeroed.